# SELECT * from table where?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I was working on this where I have 2 variables

- $pmid
- $pmid2

And a table with few variables and 2 principal columns that I am going to use for this script

- pmid
- pmid2

Now What I want it to do is to check if $pmid or $pmid is matching pmid in table or pmid2 any of the variables to match any of these two table columns mentioned
Here's My script:

```
$selectpm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE pmid=($chat_id OR $chat_id2) AND pmid2=($ chat_id OR $chat_id2)");
```

Of Course my code is wrong its just how I tough It could work , But I don't know how exactly is supposed to work thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use:

```
 $selectpm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE pmid
 IN($chat_id,$chat_id2) OR pmid2 IN($chat_id,$chat_id2)");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can do it

```
SELECT * FROM pm 
WHERE 
( 
  pmid=$chat_id OR  pmid= $chat_id2
) 
AND (
 pmid2 = $chat_id OR pmid2 = $chat_id2
)


$selectpm = mysql_query(
"SELECT * FROM pm 
WHERE ( pmid=$chat_id OR  pmid= $chat_id2 )
 AND (pmid2 = $chat_id OR pmid2 = $chat_id2)");
```

A better way is to write the query in a variable as

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM pm 
       WHERE 
       ( pmid=$chat_id OR  pmid= $chat_id2 )
       AND (pmid2 = $chat_id OR pmid2 = $chat_id2)" ;

$selectpm = mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: Thats some PHP error , check that part I have updated the question

Comment: Yes, That might work, But Somebody answered ^^ Ill try and tell you if it works thou

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `in` clause

```
SELECT * FROM pm 
WHERE pmid in ($chat_id , $chat_id2)
AND pmid2 in ($chat_id , $chat_id2)
```